# Query data, trying to avoid using a Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
organiz: pk = org_id
individu: pk = ind_id
address: pk = address_id
```

Both `organiz` and `individu` contains an `address_id`. Each row in `individu` contains an `org_id`. Basically, an "individual" belongs to an "organization". I'd like a query that gives me the `address_id` of everyone that has a specific `org_id`.

Here is what I tried before, but it only gives me the `address_id` for all of my individu's.

```
select
    a.Address_id,
    a.Address_Line_1,
    a.Address_Line_2,
    a.Address_City,
    a.Address_State_Code,
    a.Address_Zip,
    o.Phone_Number

from
    address a inner join individu i on a.address_id = i.address_id
    inner join organiz o on o.org_id = i.org_id
where
    a.Address_Line_1 is not null
    and o.org_id = 808474
```

To get it to work, I used a union to then query the address ID for the organiz:

```
select
    a.Address_id,
    a.Address_Line_1,
    a.Address_Line_2,
    a.Address_City,
    a.Address_State_Code,
    a.Address_Zip,
    o.Phone_Number

from
    address a inner join individu i on a.address_id = i.address_id
    inner join organiz o on o.org_id = i.org_id
where
    a.Address_Line_1 is not null
    and o.org_id = 808474
UNION
select
    a.Address_id,
    a.Address_Line_1,
    a.Address_Line_2,
    a.Address_City,
    a.Address_State_Code,
    a.Address_Zip,
    o.Phone_Number
from 
    address a inner join organiz o on a.address_id = o.address_id
where
    o.org_id = 808474
    and a.Address_Line_1 is not null
```

Is there another method so I can avoid using a UNION?

Comment: What's bad in a `UNION`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the `UNION` into the inner query:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    address
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  ad.address_id
        FROM    organiz o
        CROSS APPLY
                (
                SELECT  address_id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  i.address_id
                FROM    individu i
                WHERE   i.org_id = o.org_id
                ) ad
        WHERE   o.org_id = @myorgid
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can.

```
Select StuffYouWant 
From Address 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM organiz 
                WHERE Address.address_id = organiz.address_id 
                    AND SEARCH_CRITERIA) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM individu
                WHERE Address.address_id = individu.address_id 
                AND SEARCH_CRITERIA)
```